# How to visualize only high correlations for better representation of the huge correlation matrix?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

Is there a way to show only high correlations (like `correlations>=.9`) in the huge correlation matrix like the one below?
It will filter some captions like (2,3,5,6,8,9,...), and one possible solution is to reduce feature size to important ones.

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want. Do you want to select only rows and columns that contain at least one higher correlation value (say > 0.90), or do you want to nullify lower correlations sothat the higher ones are visible on a "white" background?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart The first one; I want to select only rows and columns that contain at least one higher correlation value.

Comment: you can use a logarithmic scale: sns.heatmap(np.log(df.corr()))

Comment: @warped Could you please give an example?

Comment: just try to use the code in my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following, where `df.max(axis=1) > 0.90` is inspecting rowwise if there is at least one correlation that is over 0.90, and axis=0 for columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10,10)))

ndf = df.loc[df.max(axis=1) > 0.90, df.max(axis=0) > 0.90]

sns.heatmap(ndf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you please elaborate on ndf = df.loc[df.max(axis=1) > threshold, df.max(axis=0) > threshold].

Comment: Great to help. Note that I removed one minute ago `.corr()` from the heatmap line. The code `ndf = df.loc[df.max(axis=1) > threshold, df.max(axis=0) > threshold]` can be broken down to `df.max(axis=1) > threshold` and `df.max(axis=0) > threshold`. These parts return rowwise and columnwise a boolean index with `True` values for rows and columns that contained at least one value that was larger than 0.90.

Comment: Oh, now it's not working well. Please `annot=True` to see the results.

Comment: My answers assumes there are already correlations in the matrix. If this is not the case, first do `df_correlations = df.corr()`.

Comment: This is your sample results: [link](https://pasteboard.co/JMkk6QH.png). It has to be correlations higher than a threshold, which is not.

Comment: It keeps the rows and columns that have *at least* one value greater than 0.90. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228102/discussion-between-flodude-and-ruthger-righart).